# Oanda API - Issue Price - Instruments

Tags: api, broker, oanda

I'm using Oanda API to automate Trading strategies, I have a 'price' error that only occurs when selecting some instruments such as XAG (silver), my guess is that there is a classification difference but Oanda is yet to answer on the matter.

The error does not occur when selecting Forex pairs.

If anyone had such issues in the past and managed to solve it I'll be happy to hear form them.

PS: I'm UK based and have access to most products including CFDs

```
class SMABollTrader(tpqoa.tpqoa):
def __init__(self, conf_file, instrument, bar_length, SMA, dev, SMA_S, SMA_L, units):
    super().__init__(conf_file)
    self.instrument = instrument
    self.bar_length = pd.to_timedelta(bar_length)
    self.tick_data = pd.DataFrame()
    self.raw_data = None
    self.data = None 
    self.last_bar = None
    self.units = units
    self.position = 0
    self.profits = []
    self.price = []
    
    #*****************add strategy-specific attributes here******************
    self.SMA = SMA
    self.dev = dev
    self.SMA_S = SMA_S
    self.SMA_L = SMA_L
    #************************************************************************
 
def get_most_recent(self, days = 5):
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        now = now - timedelta(microseconds = now.microsecond)
        past = now - timedelta(days = days)
        df = self.get_history(instrument = self.instrument, start = past, end = now,
                               granularity = "S5", price = "M", localize = False).c.dropna().to_frame()
        df.rename(columns = {"c":self.instrument}, inplace = True)
        df = df.resample(self                                                 .bar_length, label = "right").last().dropna().iloc[:-1]
        self.raw_data = df.copy()
        self.last_bar = self.raw_data.index[-1]
        if pd.to_datetime(datetime.utcnow()).tz_localize("UTC") - self.last_bar < self.bar_length:
            break
            
            
def on_success(self, time, bid, ask):
    print(self.ticks, end = " ")
    
    recent_tick = pd.to_datetime(time)
    df = pd.DataFrame({self.instrument:(ask + bid)/2}, 
                      index = [recent_tick])
    self.tick_data = self.tick_data.append(df)
    
    if recent_tick - self.last_bar > self.bar_length:
        self.resample_and_join()
        self.define_strategy()
        self.execute_trades()

def resample_and_join(self):
    self.raw_data = self.raw_data.append(self.tick_data.resample(self.bar_length, 
                                                              label="right").last().ffill().iloc[:-1])
    self.tick_data = self.tick_data.iloc[-1:]
    self.last_bar = self.raw_data.index[-1]

def define_strategy(self): # "strategy-specific"
    df = self.raw_data.copy()
  
    #******************** define your strategy here ************************

    df["SMA"] = df[self.instrument].rolling(self.SMA).mean()
    df["Lower"] = df["SMA"] - df[self.instrument].rolling(self.SMA).std() * self.dev
    df["Upper"] = df["SMA"] + df[self.instrument].rolling(self.SMA).std() * self.dev
    df["distance"] = df[self.instrument] - df.SMA
    df["SMA_S"] = df[self.instrument].rolling(self.SMA_S).mean()
    df["SMA_L"] = df[self.instrument].rolling(self.SMA_L).mean()
    
  
    df["position"] = np.where(df[self.instrument] < df.Lower) and np.where(df["SMA_S"] > df["SMA_L"] ,1,np.nan)
    df["position"] = np.where(df[self.instrument] > df.Upper) and np.where(df["SMA_S"] < df["SMA_L"], -1, df["position"])
    df["position"] = np.where(df.distance * df.distance.shift(1) < 0, 0, df["position"])
    df["position"] = df.position.ffill().fillna(0)
    
   
    self.data = df.copy()   
 
    #***********************************************************************

                              
    
def execute_trades(self):

    if self.data["position"].iloc[-1] == 1:
        if self.position == 0 or None:
            order = self.create_order(self.instrument, self.units, suppress = True, ret = True)
            self.report_trade(order, "GOING LONG")
        elif self.position == -1:
            order = self.create_order(self.instrument, self.units * 2, suppress = True, ret = True) 
            self.report_trade(order, "GOING LONG")
        self.position = 1
    elif self.data["position"].iloc[-1] == -1: 
        if self.position == 0:
            order = self.create_order(self.instrument, -self.units, suppress = True, ret = True)
            self.report_trade(order, "GOING SHORT")
        elif self.position == 1:
            order = self.create_order(self.instrument, -self.units * 2, suppress = True, ret = True)
            self.report_trade(order, "GOING SHORT")
        self.position = -1
    elif self.data["position"].iloc[-1] == 0: 
        if self.position == -1:
            order = self.create_order(self.instrument, self.units, suppress = True, ret = True)
            self.report_trade(order, "GOING NEUTRAL")
        elif self.position == 1:
            order = self.create_order(self.instrument, -self.units, suppress = True, ret = True) 
            self.report_trade(order, "GOING NEUTRAL")
        self.position = 0

def report_trade(self, order, going):
    time = order["time"]
    units = order["units"]
    price = order["price"]
    pl = float(order["pl"])
    self.profits.append(pl)
    cumpl = sum(self.profits)
    print("\n" + 100* "-")
    print("{} | {}".format(time, going))
    print("{} | units = {} | price = {} | P&L = {} | Cum P&L = {}".format(time, units, price, pl, cumpl))
    print(100 * "-" + "\n")  

trader = SMABollTrader("oanda.cfg", "EUR_GBP", "15m", SMA = 82, dev = 4, SMA_S = 38, SMA_L = 135, units = 100000)

trader.get_most_recent()
```

trader.stream_data(trader.instrument, stop = None )
if trader.position != 0: # if we have a final open position
close_order = trader.create_order(trader.instrument, units = -trader.position * trader.units,
suppress = True, ret = True)
trader.report_trade(close_order, "GOING NEUTRAL")
trader.signal = 0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have done Hagmann course as well and I have recognised your code immediately.

Firstly the way you define your positions is not the best. Look at the section of combining two strategies. There are two ways.

Now regarding your price problem I had a similar situation with BTC. You can download it's historical data but when I plotted it to the strategy code and started to stream I had exactly the same error indicating that tick data was never streamed.

I am guessing that simply not all instruments are tradeable via api or in your case maybe you tried to stream beyond trading hours?